# How to enable RWC on modules

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm doing a study on byte patching protection.The algorithm of my work is about to check if pages are shared or not. If somehow my modules are manipulated in any way ( byte patching ), the pages need to be copied. How can I set all modules in the Process according to this - or - after they are loaded?